# What is the function for a 'fractal sine wave'?

Tags: functions, approximation

Maybe I abused the word fractal here. I was wondering what's the function ( if not functions ) for this wave:

[image: 'fractal' sine wave]

My attempt was this function, It looks the same, but It's not.
The second sine wave is following the envelope of the first, somewhat following the 90-degree angle of the first sine wave.

$y=\frac{sin(200*x)}{10}+sin(x)$

[image: wave]

[image: wave1]

Comment: PS: Sorry the axis weren't proportional.

Comment: That doesn't even look like a function -- it goes backwards near the middle of your plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not what you had in mind, but this is what you get with the parametric equation below:

$$x=t-\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}0.15\sin(12t)\\
y=\sin(t)+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}0.15\sin(12t)$$

[image]

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Which was gotten by computing the upwards unit normal vector, scaling by $0.15\sin(12t)$ (because the small waves go through 12 periods while the main sine wave goes through 1 in the original graphic, and eyeballing the figure $0.15$), then adding it to the original parametrization.

Comment: @whacka: obviously :) If you feel in a good shape, you can derive the equation with an added third generation wave :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are actually looking for a *fractal* sine wave, you probably mean this function from Weierstrauss:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac 23\right)^n\cos(9^n\pi x)$$

The main fame of this function is that it is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

Here are the first four partial sums of that series, for $n=0,1,2,3$. The graph you show is similar to the second one, which has the equation

$$f1(x)=\cos(\pi x)+\frac 23\cos(9\pi x)$$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for functions of the form

$y=a\sin(bx)+c\sin(dx)$

with $a,b,c,d$ positive constants.

For example: Try $a=1,b=1,c=.3,d=12$ to start with -- and play around with it till it matches your purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped my formula. This is what I already tried.