# How would one describe this function?

Tags: trigonometry, recursion

I have this image/idea in my head of a recursive function that is essentially a sine wave that is composed of itself. Bear with me as I am not entirely sure of the terminology to use.

The closest I can figure is something like sin(x)/4 + sin(x/16), but if you were to "zoom in" on one period of the "inner" wave, it would be made up of more waves, and likewise if you zoom out.

Is there a name for this equation/this type of equation?

I know this is pretty vague, so feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: I do not know of any particular name, but you can find more of it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484403/what-is-the-function-for-a-fractal-sine-wave/1484422). Or in general, google for "fractal sine wave".

Comment: Yes! The Weierstrass function is essentially what I'm talking about. I can't believe I didn't think of the word fractal to describe it. Thanks!