# A sequence of fractal sine wave curves

Tags: functions, curves, periodic-functions, fractals, fractional-calculus

I am trying to find a more general answer to the question [What is the function for a 'fractal sine wave'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484403/what-is-the-function-for-a-fractal-sine-wave/1484422#1484422), i.e. an intuitive generalized definition for a sequence of curves, where
$$ \gamma_n(t) = (x_n(t), y_n(t)),$$
where for $n=0$
$$\gamma_0(t) = (t, \sin(t)),$$
and for $n=1,$
$$\gamma_1(t) = (x_1(t), y_1(t)),$$
where
$$x_1(t)=t-\sqrt{2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}\frac{\sin(12 t)}{12}\\
y_1(t)=\sin(t)+\sqrt{2}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}\frac{\sin(12 t)}{12},$$

the following graph will most likely illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Graph]

What is the next step? How does the next graph like look like and how does it look in general?
How does it look as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Note: Maybe, the following criterions could be applicable:
$$\frac{d\gamma_n}{dt}(t)|_{t=0} = (0, n+1)\\$$
$$ (x_n(t) -x_{n-1}(t))^2 + (y_n(t) -y_{n-1}(t))^2 =(n+1) \frac{y_{n-1}^2(12t)}{12^2}$$

Comment: I think R.Daulton's answer in the linked post gives already a general look, you can adapt de coefficients and period.

Comment: Am I right in saying that what you want is formulae for a sequence of parametric curves given by drawing a "sine wave" that oscillates along the previous curve, and a possible discussion of fractal behaviour in the limit?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, that is exactly what I have in mind, where each next curve oscillates with a twelve times smaller period.

Comment: Very good question! One might apply a similar construction to the one used in the answer you linked, where $\gamma_{n + 1} = \gamma_n + \mathbf n f(t)$, where $f(t) = 0.15^n \sin(12^n t)$, and $\mathbf n$ is a unit normal $\mathbf n = (-\dot y_n, \dot x_n) / \sqrt{\dot x_n^2 + \dot y_n^2}$. However I think this starts to look quite unaesthetic after a few iterations because really we want $f$ to be parametrised by the arc length after each iteration (otherwise, if $\gamma_n$ moves quickly, $\gamma_{n + 1}$ gets stretched out). I think this makes the whole problem harder to solve symbolically

Comment: Like, you could define $\ell_n(t) = \int_0^t \lvert \dot \gamma_n(\nu) \rvert \,\mathrm d\nu$, which is clearly increasing, so has an inverse, and then let $\gamma_{n + 1} = \gamma_n + \mathbf n f(\ell_n^{-1}(t))$. However I have no idea how I'd even go about graphing this to check if that's sensible. (Maybe one of these new-fangled Mathematica things could manage it)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Maybe there exists a different kind of periodic function that has better properties for this iterative process than the sine. I was also thinking how this would work with a cycloid.

Comment: Or maybe the function could be the elliptic projection onto a plane. [elliptic curve](http://jrjohnson.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/A11StarChart-S1.jpg)
(a question I asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-the-ecliptic-as-shown-in-this-picture-be-calculated-as-a-rigorous-mathematical-function-It-seems-that-it-would-very-closely-resemble-a-sine-function-is-that-the-case-Can-someone-explicitly-write-it-down))